# How to order requests in Rapid Api Vs Code Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, rapidapi

I recently discovered the Rapid Api vs code extension which is really good and convenient. Now deciding to move all of my apis from Postman to the vs code extension, I see that they're all there exactly in the order in which I inserted them and I don't seem to find a button or a way to order them so I'm wondering whether there's a way in the settings to order the apis by name or a search functionality to avoid scrolling down at the search of a specific api.

Answer (score 0):

we are working on some updates to the Tree View. You can move the order by dragging and dropping a request to a different section of the tree.  Click and hold to the left of an item in the tree and you will be able to drag and drop to re-order.